# How can I statistically assess directionality for larger tables of count data (eg 2x3, 2x4)?

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, count-data, odds-ratio, fishers-exact-test

I have an experiment with 2 dependent variables (each binary decisions) that makes some quite distinct hypothesis about the manipulation. As there are 2 dependent variables, there are 4 outcomes that are possible. H0 is that participants assigned to treatment A will prefer **one** of those outcomes, whereas those assigned to treatment B will prefer **the other three** outcomes (highlighted in **bold** below).

Eg, if n is 317 participants, I would expect something like:

| Outcome | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | 21 | **34** |
| 01 | 17 | **40** |
| 10 | 35 | **62** |
| 11 | **63** | 45 |

Participants are randomised to either A or B.

So the underlying data by participant might look something like this:

| Participant | Condition | X1 | X2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | A | 1 | 1 |
| P2 | A | 1 | 1 |
| P3 | A | 1 | 1 |
| P4 | A | 0 | 0 |
| P5 | B | 1 | 0 |
| P6 | B | 0 | 0 |
| P7 | B | 1 | 1 |
| P8 | B | 0 | 0 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| PN |  |  |  |

The background is that this is a legal case where the manipulation ought legally to have nothing to do with the dependent variable, but in does in fact because it allows the participants to favour the party that they have sympathy with.

If I do a Chi2 or Fisher's Exact Test, this does not seem to reflect the hypothesis as I think it would just be testing that 1 of the 4 dependent variables will be higher or lower. H1 is quite distinctive in that it claims that it will be **1** out of 16 possible combinations (ie 2 x 2 x 2 x 2), whereas a Chi2 or Fisher's test would be that it would be **any** out of those 16 possible combinations.

Equally, a *post hoc* Fisher's Exact test comparing pairs of those combinations (2 x 2) could be directional, but would not be testing the prediction made by H1.

Alternatively, is there another, presumably more sophisticated statistical test, that that would be appropriate for testing this data?

Comment: Can you give more details about the design? A is without treatment, B is with treatmenty? Subjects are randomized to A or B? Sample size? The four dependent variables are observed for each of the subjects? ...'

Comment: It's a legal case where the participants have to decide issues. Each of the issues favours either one side or the other. Then there is a character manipulation where A is that one of the sides is of good character, B is where that side is of bad character. None of the issues should be influenced by character, but that is exactly what we seem to see.

Comment: Please add extra info as an edit to the post. We want posts to be self-contained, and comments are easily overlooked and can be deleted. And, I still want more clarity, sample size, randomization, ... The question is an interesting one!

Comment: Added more detail above. I hope this is helpful!

Comment: This is better, but is still not clear to me ... each participant is represented only once in the table, so there are two binary issues, and the four combinations then represent 00, 01, 10, 11? yes? I think it would be better but not sure, too have two separate columns of responses for the two issues. Then one possibility would be two binary logistic regressions, with some shared parameters, but need too think more, and out of time just now ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this could reasonably be analysed as a $2\times2\times2$ table using a Poisson log-linear model.

You could start by defining a mutual independence model for the two decisions and condition. In this model, both of the decisions and condition are unrelated to one another in how they impact the counts in the table. In R you can fit this using `glm` with the `poisson` family.

```r
# Load the data
df <- data.frame(
  decision1 = rep(0:1, each = 2),
  decision2 = rep(0:1, times = 2),
  condition = rep(0:1, each = 4),
  count = c(21, 17, 35, 63, 34, 40, 62, 45)
)

# Mutual independence model
m0 <- glm(count ~ decision1 + decision2 + condition,
          data = df,
          family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

The coefficients here are just the log-odds of each factor independent of any other factors in the model. This model is only really useful inasmuch as it helps define a null to test against, and roughly translates to your statement that the condition ought legally to have nothing to do with the decisions.

Based on your hypothesis, let's now fit a model that adds a main effect of selecting one for both decisions and an interaction between this variable and the condition.

```r
# Create dummy variable for decision 1 & 2
df$decision12 <- with(df, ifelse(decision1 == 1 & decision2 == 1, 1, 0))

# Update the model to add main effect and interaction
m1 <- update(m0, ~ . + decision12 + decision12:condition)
summary(m1)

Call:
glm(formula = count ~ decision1 + decision2 + condition + decision12 + 
    condition:decision12, family = poisson(link = "log"), data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
      1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8  
 0.4022  -0.6689   0.1913   0.0000  -0.3017   0.4716  -0.1413   0.0000  

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           2.95546    0.16461  17.955  < 2e-16 ***
decision1             0.56738    0.16879   3.361 0.000776 ***
decision2             0.03572    0.18901   0.189 0.850115    
condition             0.62220    0.14509   4.288 1.80e-05 ***
decision12            0.58458    0.26612   2.197 0.028046 *  
condition:decision12 -0.95867    0.24320  -3.942 8.08e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 51.59791  on 7  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  0.97918  on 2  degrees of freedom
AIC: 56.448

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

The main effect coefficients in this model aren't very interpretable, but the interaction term is - it's the log-odds ratio of selecting one for both decisions, as opposed to another combination of decisions, in condition B relative to condition A. The odds of selecting this combination of decisions was $2.6$ times higher in condition A compared to condition B ($1/\exp(-.959)=2.6$).

We can test this model representing your hypothesis against the null model in R using `anova`.

```r
anova(m0, m1, test = "Chisq")
> Analysis of Deviance Table
> 
> Model 1: count ~ decision1 + decision2 + condition
> Model 2: count ~ decision1 + decision2 + condition + decision12 + condition:decision12
>   Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
> 1         4    16.9656                          
> 2         2     0.9792  2   15.986 0.0003378 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Given this result, we'd reject the null model of mutual independence in favour of the model based on your hypothesis that the condition influences one specific pair of decisions. Note the very low residual deviance for the latter model as well - we'd be hard pressed to fit a better model for this data.

One caveat to this approach is that loglinear models don't distinguish between dependent and independent variables per se, but instead capture and test for patterns of association between variables in a table (analogous to a correlation). As a test of your hypothesis though, I think this is acceptable (and arguably more intuitive than say, a bivariate logit/probit model, which might also be applicable).

For more background on these types of models, see Chapter 9 of Agresti (2012). Categorical data analysis (3rd Ed).

Comment: this is fantastic, a really helpful and insightful answer. I had not previously used a log-likelihood regression, but I can see how it would be appropriate here. One question - if we are creating a dummy variable "decision12" by combining "decision1" and "decision2", we are effectively reducing the four combinations to two. Would this mean that it would be possible to use a logistic regression, comparing a model with a parameter for the dummy variable with a model that also has a parameter for condition?

Comment: You're right - the model does reduce the combinations. You could run a logistic with `glm(decision12 ~ condition, data = df, family = binomial, weights = count)` - the log-odds condition estimate will be identical (-.959). This model collapses both decisions into 1 binary outcome (11 or another combination), predicted by condition. Whether that model is sensible is up to you. I mainly proposed log-linear models to allow you to set up a null model incorporating both decisions and condition (albeit as independent factors, like in a traditional chi-square test), to compare with your alternative.